# Passing parameters from shell script to java class

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, wavemaker

I'm aware there's plenty of related questions out there, however I seem to be stuck on something that should be trivial. I have written a java service in Wavemaker, which on the click of a button passes 2 string parameters (bound to editors on the front end), into a shell script on our Linux box. I use a process builder in the java service to access to the shell script. The code is as follows.

```
package com.wavemeker;
import com.wavemaker.runtime.javaservice.JavaServiceSuperClass;
import com.wavemaker.runtime.service.annotations.ExposeToClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
/*
 * This is a client-facing service class.  All
 * public methods will be exposed to the client.  Their return
 * values and parameters will be passed to the client or taken
 * from the client, respectively.  This will be a singleton
 * instance, shared between all requests.  
 * To log, call the superclass method log(LOG_LEVEL, String) or   log(LOG_LEVEL, String, Exception).
 * LOG_LEVEL is one of FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO and DEBUG to modify your log  level.
* For info on these levels, look for tomcat/log4j documentation
*/
@ExposeToClient
public class xmlGen extends JavaServiceSuperClass {
    public void readScript(String a, String b) throws IOException, InterruptedException
     {             
              final File dir = new File("/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/sh/");
              final String shellScript = "./master_script.sh";
              ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(shellScript, a, b);
              pb.directory(dir);
              System.out.println("Executing script...");
              Process proc = pb.start();
        try {
              int shellExitStatus = proc.waitFor();
              if(shellExitStatus != 0)
              {
                System.out.println("Success!!");    
              }
              System.out.println("Script has completed successfully.");
            }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
              System.out.println("Shell Script process was interrupted and did not complete.");
              System.exit(1);
            }
    }  // end method
} // end class
```

Here the two input parameters "a" and "b" are bound to a Wavemaker service variables, so if I enter "ten" and "two" on the front screen, these are the parameters I pass to my shell script. They do in fact pass down with no problem, and "master_script.sh" executes.The issue i'm having is that this script calls a few other scripts which in turn invoke lower level java code also reliant on these two string parameters... master_script.sh looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
./script1.sh "$1" "$2"
./script2.sh "$1" "$2"  
      .
      .
      .
```

and to give an example of one of these scripts; script1.sh for example, looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
FILEPATH1=/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/data/test.txt
JPATH1=/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/java/XML/src
> $FILEPATH1 # empties file contents before writing to it...
echo "testing params $1 and $2" > $FILEPATH1
cd $JPATH1
javac pgQuery.java
java -classpath postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar:. pgQuery "$1" "$2" >> $FILEPATH1
```

So ultimately I want the output of the java class to be appended to the file "test.txt". I find it odd that the echo works fine and outputs the parameters that I entered from Wavemaker to the test file, however the java doesn't seem to be writing anything out. To make things clearer, this piece of java accesses a postgresql database via a prepared statement and gives the results of the query in xml format (query_to_xml). For completeness, the code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.*;

public class pgQuery
{   // Begin Class
    // JDBC driver name and db URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://path...";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "username";
    static final String PASS = "password";

public void xml(int a, int b) {   // Begin Main Method

Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;

try  //***START TRY BLOCK****//
{
// Register JDBC driver
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

// Open a connection
//System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

String sql0 = "select query_to_xml('select cdt as CreationDateAndTime from  table_name where x ='||?||' and  y = '||?||'', true,true,'');";

PreparedStatement ps0 = conn.prepareStatement(sql0);
ps0.setInt(1, a);
ps0.setInt(2, b);
ResultSet rs0 = ps0.executeQuery();

ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs0.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while(rs0.next())
{
for(int i=1;i<=numberOfColumns;i++) 
{
System.out.println(rs0.getString(i)+ " ");
}
}

ps0.close();
rs0.close();
conn.close();

}  //****END TRY BLOCK*

catch(SQLException se){
//Handle errors for JDBC
System.out.println("Error with JDBC Connection!!");
se.printStackTrace();
}
catch(Exception e){
//Handle errors for Class.forName
System.out.println("Error with Class.forName... Driver Related!!");
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
//finally block to close resources
try{
if(stmt!=null)
   stmt.close();
}
catch(SQLException se2){
}
try{
if(conn!=null)
   conn.close();
}
catch(SQLException se)
{
se.printStackTrace();
}//end finally try
}//end try
}//end method

public static void main(String[] args)
{
int a1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);;
int b1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);;
pgQuery obj1 = new pgQuery();
obj1.xml(a1, b1);
} // end main method
}//end Class
```

If I execute "master_script.sh "$1" "$2" directly from linux it all works beautifully. I have tried every combination of double quotes and single quotes around the parameters I can think of but alas, the output of the java code is not being written to this test file from the press of a button on the Wavemaker front end.
I'm aware this is a bit of a lengthy problem but if anyone had any insight as to why this is not working i'd be most grateful. I'm sure i'm just overlooking something silly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: redirection from java command to an output file works just fine in bash/linux.  i suggest you try to simplify your solution to find the root cause of your problem. possibly runtime exception is thrown and there's no output. you don't really have enough logging in your pgOutput class to be helpful. classes should not start with a lower case letter. 
[m@d83 ~]$ echo 'public class Foo { public static void main(String[] a) { System.out.println("A"); } }' > Foo.java
[m@d083 ~]$ javac Foo.java
[m@d83 ~]$ java Foo A B > Foo.log
[m@d83 ~]$ cat Foo.log 
A

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark, there all good points.I usually rename everything when I post here. The lower case "p" was a typo. You are correct though, the solution does need to be simplified. I don't have any problem redirecting the output of the java if I run it directly from Linux. Its only when I execute the script + parameters from the process builder above (which is activated from a wavemaker button click) that the java fails to redirect to the file.. Yet the parameters echo out to that file no problem. I will try to simplify what I have nevertheless, and thanks again for the response.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the java compilation line in the shell script; `javac pgQuery.java` the parameters passed down without issue. I don't particularly understand why this is, and it was only by chance that I happened to comment out that line in the script and run it. I guess once the java code remains unchanged it doesn't need to be compiled every time I execute the script, however I still don't get why compiling every time would have prevented the passing of parameters. Either way, I thought i'd post this in case it ever proves useful to anyone.